# Auto Complete Ajax Tool Kit VB.NET ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Hi people I am stuck to how to use the ajax tool kit autocomplete extender to obtain records from a database, I have looked at the following:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tZiVY8qs1c
http://www.andreavb.com/forum/viewtopic_9310.html
http://forums.asp.net/t/1626754.aspx/1
http://www.programmersheaven.com/article/100738-Using+AutoComplete+in+the+AJAX+Toolkit+in+VB.NET/info.aspx
http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-autocomplete-in-the-ajax-toolkit-in-vb-net/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cd3aa3/creating-auto-complete-textbox-using-autocompleteextender-control-of-ajax/
```

I cant seem to find one that will help me use a asp.net database rather the ones shown here are all website driven and not database. Could you please help me in creating or directing me to a tutorial in which aids me to create an auto compleate in vb.net aspx pages 2010 using a database

I have a test database with one table and inside the table the following attributes:

```
TESTID int PK
Name nvarchar(100)
LName nvarchar(100)
```

Thank You for any help provided

EDIT:

when i try to add a (Add autocomplete Page Method) I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error (TargetInvocationException); Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokedMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo  method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignaureStruct@sig,
```

"and it continutes with lots of more writting"

when i press ok

my aspx page shows the following code with a green underline:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Function GetComletionList() As System.String[]

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a web service, to return the data.  Within the vb code of this web service, connect to the database and retrieve the data.

Comment: I am trying to add a (Add autocomplete Page Method) but i get an error, please look at my edited question thank you